# How do you declare the type for the `clean-element` higher-order-component in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

current error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof TextareaAutosize' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component<{}, {}, any>'.
  Property 'setState' is missing in type 'typeof TextareaAutosize'.
```

Code:

```
import clean from "clean-element";
import Textarea from "react-textarea-autosize";

const CleanInput = clean(Textarea);
```

and:

```
import * as React from 'react';

declare function clean<TPassedProps>(
  component: React.Component<TPassedProps>
): React.ComponentType<TPassedProps>;

export default clean;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `React.Component<TPassedProps>` with `React.ComponentType<TPassedProps>` should get rid of the immediate error.  But if you actually want a correct typing for the `clean` function, that's much harder.  In fact, it can't really be done because the behavior of the component returned by `clean` is dependent on the type of the `propTypes` you assign to it, and TypeScript doesn't support tracking the type of a value stored in an already declared property.  Instead, you'd have to define a wrapper function that accepts both the inner component and the `propTypes` object and computes the props type of the new component to include the props being stripped by `clean` plus the props being passed through to the inner component.  For a complete solution, one should check that `clean` isn't being used to strip props that are actually required by the inner component.  Here's what I came up with:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import clean from "clean-element";

type RequiredKeysOf<T> =
    {[K in keyof T]-?: {[P in K]?: T[K]} extends {[P in K]: T[K]} ? never : K}[keyof T];

const ERROR_SYMBOL = Symbol();
interface Cannot_clean_required_props<K extends keyof any> {
    [ERROR_SYMBOL]: undefined;
}

function cleanWithPropTypes<TPassedProps,
    TPropTypes extends React.ValidationMap<any> &
        (keyof TPropTypes & RequiredKeysOf<TPassedProps> extends never ? {} :
            Cannot_clean_required_props<keyof TPropTypes & RequiredKeysOf<TPassedProps>>)>(
    component: React.ComponentType<TPassedProps>, propTypes: TPropTypes):
    React.ComponentType<PropTypes.InferProps<TPropTypes> &
        Pick<TPassedProps, Exclude<keyof TPassedProps, keyof TPropTypes>>> {
    let cleaned = clean(component);
    cleaned.propTypes = propTypes;
    return cleaned;
}
```